# $sortArray Issue (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a section of my aggregate query that I cannot get to work for the life of me. I am running 6.0. The section of the query with the issue looks like this:

```
 $project: {
            _id: 0,
            games: {
              $sortArray: {
                input: '$games',
                sortBy: { date: -1 }
              }
            },
            total: { $size: '$games' }
          }
```

For some reason the $sortArray function is not working for me in that I am getting no output from the query at all. The query, however, will work if I remove this sort like this:

```
 $project: {
            _id: 0,
            games: 1,
            total: { $size: '$games' }
          }
```

After studying the [$sortArray documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/), I believe that I am implementing this into the pipeline correctly. Can anyone identify what the issue is? Here is the full pipeline for context:

```
      const pipeline = [
        {
          $match: { _id: ObjectID( user_id ) }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'game',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'player_id',
            pipeline: pipelineFilters,
            as: 'owned_games'
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'viewers',
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { email: user_email } },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: 'games',
                  localField: 'game_id',
                  foreignField: '_id',
                  pipeline: pipelineFilters,
                  as: 'games'
                }
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  game: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$games', 0 ] }
                }
              },
              {
                $replaceRoot: {
                  newRoot: '$game'
                }
              }
            ],
            as: 'viewing_games'
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            games: {
              $concatArrays: [ '$viewing_games', '$owned_games' ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            games: {
              $sortArray: {
                input: '$games',
                sortBy: { date: -1 }
              }
            },
            total: { $size: '$games' }
          }
        }
      ];
```

and example of the document structure right before the final $project:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6359ac2149c98388770fb2b3"),
  games: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bda1"),
      name: 'game 1',
      owner_id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd98"),
      date: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.584Z,
      status: 'draft',
      createdAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.599Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.599Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd99"),
      name: 'game 2',
      owner_id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd8b"),
      date: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z,
      status: 'draft',
      createdAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.585Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.585Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd9b"),
      name: 'game 3',
      owner_id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd8b"),
      date: 1990-01-01T01:22:00.000Z,
      status: 'draft',
      createdAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.588Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.588Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd9d"),
      name: 'game 4',
      owner_id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd8b"),
      date: 2500-10-05T14:48:00.000Z,
      status: 'draft',
      createdAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.592Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.592Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd9f"),
      name: 'game 5',
      owner_id: new ObjectId("63595544435af1b923d1bd8b"),
      date: 1995-12-25T01:22:00.000Z,
      status: 'draft',
      createdAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.595Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-10-26T15:41:56.595Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Can you give us a sample f what the document structure looks like immediately before the final `$project` that contains the `$sortArray` call? Does the `games` array contain subdocuments that each contain a `date` field to sort on? Are you running on `6.0`?

Comment: @user20042973 I went ahead and added some sample data from before the final `$project`. I am also running 6.0 yes

Comment: Strange, the final `"$project"` works fine on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VwZRYiiN1pv).

Comment: This bring us back to user20042973's question: "In what way is it not working?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using `mongo:latest` tag when launching our docker container which doesn't actually pull the latest mongo image...

**Conclusion**: assumptions are bad